# Cannot run multiple test cases in Eclipse PyUnit

Tags: selenium, python-unittest

I am working with Selenium webdriver + Python. I have some Python classes extending **unittest.TestCase** class so that each class is as good as a test case. When I try to run these test cases in Eclipse through **Run > Run As > Python unit-test**, it runs only the 1st test case (1st class), shows the output correctly and stops.

The other test cases are not run. I had posted this question earlier here but didn't get much response. It's a little critical for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Eclipse will only run the 'active' class using the `Run > Run As > Python unit-test`.

If you want to run multiple test-classes at the same time you'll need to create a 'suite class'

```
class RegressionSuite():


    def __init__(self):


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        loader = TestLoader()
        suite = TestSuite((
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(YourTestClass1),
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(YourTestClass2))

        runner = TextTestRunnerr(verbosity=2)
        runner.run(suite)
```

Comment: Each of my test case is having its own setUp() and tearDown() method and I remember, all my test cases were running earlier through PyUnit. I don't know why the hell it is not running all of them now. Is there also any setting in Eclipse that I may be overlooking?